# How to add response to swagger export?

Tags: swagger, api-doc, paw

I'm using Paw to export my api calls to a swagger doc.

The "requests" are being generating correctly, but not the "responses". They all just say:

> **default** no response description was provided for this operation

How can I add a response?

Example of my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ReDoc</title>
    <!-- needed for adaptive design -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--
    ReDoc doesn't change outer page styles
    -->
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <redoc spec-url='MerchantApiSwag.json'></redoc>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of Paw:

[image]

Screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not yet possible with Paw. It's our next step, likely to be released in the next version of Paw. Sorry for the delay & inconvenience.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Is there any plan to support it now?